# Allow other users to execute google spreadsheet scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have made a simple Google Spreadsheet with some scripting behind to update colours depending on status, set update and creation dates for rows and a few other controls.

It all works when I am editing it with my own user, but now that set spreadsheet is set to public (access via link), anyone else accessing the spreadsheet gets an error `you do not have permissions to do this action`.

I am using `onEdit()` triggers and apparently guest users do not have permission to execute them. Do I have to configure something in order for it to work?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution but somme observations:
I made a little script and tested it on the [old](https://docs.google.com/a/ousset.net/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao02g19G1-G-dGZyY3pYN3lQZnhmM1o0VnBHU3RmbHc#gid=0) ad the [new](https://docs.google.com/a/ousset.net/spreadsheets/d/14s7Gg4x8wkS1Lu7oEBbWWWun9zsEDwwx1eC_JcrSFD0/edit#gid=0) spreadsheet type:

```
function imwatchingus(event) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(event));
  try{
    if(event.value=="faux"){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setBackground("red");
    }
    else if(event.value=="vrai"){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setBackground("green");
    }
    else{
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setBackground("blue");
    }
  }
  catch(e){}
}


function spyonme(){
  var trigs = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var func = [];
  for (var i in trigs){
    func.push(trigs[i].getHandlerFunction());
  }
  if(func.indexOf("imwatchingus")>-1){
    return("already enrolled");
  }
  else{
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("imwatchingus").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).onEdit().create();
    return("enrolling you");
  }
}
```

the function `imwatchingus` is the one that will do the job (it colors the background of the cell in red / green / blue depending on his text).
to have this function working I added a trigger to it. You can do that with the menu or launching the function `spyonme`.

On the New spreadsheet there is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3496). Only the first cell (A1) will be modified, but you can use this script if you are anonymous.
On the old spreadsheet, the color is applyed on the changed cell, but it's not working in anonymous mode.